# Numpy/Scipy convert raw values to indexed timeseries?

Tags: numpy, statistics, scipy, time-series

I've looked at the numpy/scipy documentation, but I can't find any builtin function to do this.

I'd like to convert raw numbers (temperatures, as it happens) representing a time series from their raw state to an indexed series (i.e. first value is 100, subsequent values are scaled against the first raw value). So, if the raw values are `(15,7.5,5)`, the indexed values would be `(100,50,33)` (mental calculation, hence int values).

This is moderately easy to code oneself, but I'd like to use a builtin if possible. A homebrew is:

```
def indexise(seq,base=0,scale=100):
    if not base:
        base=seq[0]
    return (i*scale/base for i in seq)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `seq` is a numpy array, then instead of `(i*scale/base for i in seq)`, you can use a numpy vectorized operation `scale*seq/base`.

Here's how I might modify your function:

```
import numpy as np

def indexise(seq, base=None, scale=100):
    seq = np.asfarray(seq)
    if base is None:
        base = seq[0]
    result = scale*seq/base
    return result
```

For example,

```
In [14]: indexise([15, 7.5, 5, 3, 10, 12])
Out[14]: 
array([ 100.        ,   50.        ,   33.33333333,   20.        ,
         66.66666667,   80.        ])

In [15]: indexise([15, 7.5, 5, 3, 10, 12], base=10)
Out[15]: array([ 150.,   75.,   50.,   30.,  100.,  120.])
```

Comment: Cool, thank you! I'm surprised there's nothing like this already.

Comment: I'm sorry Marcin, I never intended to cause offence I did not see your points just read and commented on your comment.

Comment: @Greg You don't need to tell people to accept an answer, especially when the question is new. I generally wait until there is a perfect answer (here one supplying a builtin), or give it a few days before accepting the best one.